# How to deserialize json string NOT to List<object> in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

i'm working with Vk.com api, in particular with this json string:

```
{
"response":
[338775,
{"aid":108787020,
"owner_id":2373452,
"artist":" Moby",
"title":"Flowers",
"duration":208,
"url":"https:\/\/cs1-50v4.vk-cdn.net\/p3\/c762273870cc49.mp3?extra=t9I-RMkSlAHkhe8JtOUUZBTZqkFVE9MJ_Q-TPmOhxPHTfHazQWEYBf4LqrOY64xLX9AuzaKwvLo4PECSFiHyWM53WMDWVcBAZVT5jlIbZ9X8ag","lyrics_id":"6060508",
"genre":22}
]
}
```

I have a class for parsing data:

```
public class AlbumResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("artist")]
        public string artist { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("duration")]
        public string duration { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

And List for deserialization:

```
public class VkAlbum
{
    public List<AlbumResponse> response { get; set; }
}
```

Than I use

```
var album = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VkAlbum>(responseText);
```

BUT it doesn't work (A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException') because of "338775" after "response".
So how can I deserialize it without using

```
 public List<object> response { get; set; }
```

instead of my AlbumResponse class?

Comment: Serialize it to List<Object> and then skip the first element, and deseriaize it again to whatever type you want.

Comment: @OrelEraki Notice *So how can I deserialize it without using public List<object> response { get; set; }*

Comment: You will always have a number before the actual List ? if so, we can remove it by search and replacing it, and then apply a deserialization.

Comment: @OrelEraki No, not in all cases i have a number. Actually, without it my code works. 
Ok, how can I remove/replace/delete these hateful numbers here from response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primitive JSON sanitation for your disposal. Not the most elegant code, but i'm sure you can take it from here.

```
responseText = Regex.Replace(responseText, "[\t|\r\n]", "");
if (responseText.IndexOf("response\": [") != -1)
{
    int start = responseText.IndexOf('[') + 1;
    int end = responseText.IndexOf(',', start);
    responseText = responseText.Substring(0, start) + responseText.Substring(end + 1);
}
var album = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VkAlbum>(responseText);
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. :(
Problem still the same

Comment: UPD NO NO NO, I'm an idiot and wrote it wrong.
It works!

Answer (score 0):

technically json response is not equivalent to C# `List<AlbumResponse>`. JSON array allows mixed types so essentially it can contains numbers and other nested objects, in your case `AlbumResponse`.

you can avoid exception by using `List<object>` and checking it's first element if it's number, if it is, ignore or do whatever you want to do and typecast 2nd element in list to `AlbumResponse`.

e.g.

```
var res = response [1] as AlbumResponse;
if(res!=null)
{
    // do something interesting...
```